# Python pandas - group by weekly data throughout different years - resample

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to use 'groupby' to group 3-years of daily data into weekly data.

So, I'd like to get only the data linked to the four weeks of Jan-2017, then Feb-2017 and so on until Dec-2019.

The code that I have so far and an example of the raw data are shown below:

```
prices = pd.read_csv("name_of_file.csv", header=1, index_col=0)    
prices.index = pd.to_datetime(prices.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')    
a=prices.groupby(prices.index.week).head(1)    
c=prices.groupby(prices.index.week).tail(1)
```

a & c output the desired data for 2017 & 2019, but not for 2018. 
Using resample('w').mean() works fine, but again I want the exact data not the mean of it.

```
                  A        AAL         AAP  
Date                                                                         
2017-01-03  45.265160  44.906567  169.691284  
2017-01-04  45.859093  45.294525  171.083817  
2017-01-05  45.313847  44.508907  170.964462  
2017-01-06  46.725651  44.819275  168.726456  
2017-01-09  46.871700  45.663097  168.626968
```

Would you have an idea on how to achieve the above? 
Thanks

Comment: if not `mean` then how do you want to aggregate the weekly data? `sum`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question properly (the lack of sample data doesn't help too).

What I think you want is to aggregate weekly data using different functions for each of the columns, i.e. take *first* values of each week for `a` and `b` columns and *last* values - for column `c`.

If so, try this one:

```py
prices.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="W")]).agg({"a": "first", "b": "first", "c": "last"})
```

*(you could use other means of aggregation too, like* `{"a": "sum", "b": "mean", ...}`)

---

### UPD.

try `df.resample("W").first()` or `df.resample("7D").first()`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I don't want to aggregate data, I just want to select from daily data, weekly data groups. Let's say the data for Jan-2017 goes from 1-Jan, 2-Jan... up until to 31-Jan, what I want to do is from those 31 days just select/pull the data/prices for 7-Jan, 14-Jan, 21-Jan, and 28-Jan and so on for any other month.

Comment: @jimfromtheoffice, in that case maybe try `df.resample("W").first()` or `df.resample("7D").first()`

Comment: @jimfromtheoffice great, glad I could help!